# How to easily versioning my solutions (and keep database)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC website. Each time I do important modifications, I copy/paste the entire folder of my solution and rename it something like MySolution v1.1, next time MySolution v1.2, ... In that way, I can always step back easily and keep versions. But I always have problems with the database.

Example:

- I work on MySolution v1.1 with the database in the App_Data named MyDB1.mdf
- I copy/paste previous version in MySolution v1.2 folder
- I cannot run successfully this newly created solution because Visual Studio will try to recreate the database named MyDB1.mdf but this one already exist (in the previous folder).
- I had to change database name in the connectionstring of the web.config file and clean the App_Data folder.

This is not a good way of doing things. Furthermore, I lost my data in my DB because I delete it each time.

Does someone can give me advices for versioning my different solutions?

I hope I was clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Each time I do important modifications, I copy/paste the entire folder of my solution and rename it something like MySolution v1.1, next time MySolution v1.2,`. If you really do that you should stop development for a while as you are doing it the wrong way and read about [revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest using a revision control system, such as [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) or Mercurial (using [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/)).  This way, you can just revert to a previous version of your code if you don't like the changes you made.

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to get familar with [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). This is really important and every developer should know about it.

Here some source control systems:

- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/)
- [GIT](http://git-scm.com/)
- [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/)

There are other version control systems as well. Personally I prefer Mercurial.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Use version control.**

If you are working in VS you can use TFS. It has good integration into it and easy to learn (free TFS for open source projects can be found on www.codeplex.com).

Also you can use GIT (www.github.com), TortoiseSVN, etc.

Also you can do versioning for Database. In this case you can store database schema in Database project or create change scripts for database.